# How to replace url instead add/push in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry guys, noob jQuery question. I found this code to change the url depending on which checkbox is selected here:
[Change href depending on checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298677/change-href-depending-on-checkboxes)
But I need to  replace the url instead add the checkbox value to the url.

Like I'm on www.katana.com/e-bikes/ and I want to redirect to www.katana.com/product/whatever   not want to stay on e-bikes subpage and continue adding the value to the url.

Thank you so much!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').on("change", function() {
        var aHrefVals = [];

        $('.checkbox').filter(":checked").each(function() {
            aHrefVals.push($(this).val());
        });

        $("a").attr("href", aHrefVals.join(","));
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you describe it in another way?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm using this code in a subdomain and it adds the value of the checkbox to the url. I don't want to add the value to the url, I want to replace the entire url with the value or redirect to the main domain with the value.

Comment: do you want to navigate to the page url built based on the checkbox input  or you want to generate the href attribute of the anchor? The code you posted does not align with the question. It does the second but if reads as if you want to achive the first

Comment: After joining the array together, you can redirect the user with window.location.href = aHrefVals.join()

Comment: Navigate to the page built based on the checkbox is enough, it-s not necessary to generate the href, I know the 3 url's I want to link to each checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do window.location.origin you will get www.katana.com . Then you can append any kind of values after the origin on checkbox change method.